# How to identify macOS system version installed (if any) on non-startup disk(s) when running High Sierra (or older)?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, security, external-disk, apfs

When running macOS High Sierra (10.13), non-startup disks formatted with newer macOS versions (10.15 or above- Catalina, Monterey, Ventura) installed on them mount as a separate "Data" volume and "Update" volume, after a warning is displayed that "incompatible" disk format has been encountered.

This is an artifact of Apple's failure to support the newer macOS version security and disk formatting (i.e. Signed System Volume (SSV), APFS) on non-startup disks when running macOS High Sierra.

The system version information for the system installed (if any) on such disks is not available and cannot be found using Disk Utility, System Profiler, Startup Disk (System Preferences), nor the diskutil command.

How can the system version installed (if any) on such disk(s) be identified when running High Sierra?

Thanks

Comment: I do not think your question is dependent on whether the disk is external or internal.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Agreed, that is correct. High Sierra is running from startup disk, which could be internal or external startup disk. Likewise, the other disk(s) that we are trying to identify the newer macOS version (if any) on are non-startup disk(s) which could be internal or external.

Comment: Edited question  (changed "external" to "non-startup") per comment. Thanks again.